# В чем разница между Type и TypeInfo?

Tags: c#, .net

По моему, они имеют похожее назначение и очень похожи между собой.

В чем практическая разница? И когда что лучше использовать?

Как я понимаю- это какая-то удобная оболочка над Type и в свежих версиях фреймворка лучше использовать TypeInfo?

В некоторых источниках пишут, что Type содержит поверхностные данные. Однако, что под этим подразумевается? Я из Type по прежнему могу полуить список полей и методов и т п.

Answer (score 7):

Из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo)

> A TypeInfo object represents the type definition itself, whereas a Type object represents a reference to the type definition. Getting a TypeInfo object forces the assembly that contains that type to load. In comparison, you can manipulate Type objects without necessarily requiring the runtime to load the assembly they reference.

Объект `TypeInfo` представляет определение типа, в то время как объект `Type` представляет ссылку на определение типа. Получение объекта `TypeInfo` приводит к  принудительной загрузке сборки, содержащей этот тип. Для сравнения, можно управлять объектами `Type` без необходимости загрузки сборок, на которые они ссылаются.

Answer (score 3):

Данный тип появился в результате рефакторинга. Он предоставляет ряд методов и свойств-помощников, которые используются для получения информации только о тех членах, которые объявлены внутри этого типа, без учёта наследования. Все эти данные вы можете получить и через `Type`, используя [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> DeclaredConstructors
public virtual IEnumerable<EventInfo> DeclaredEvents
public virtual IEnumerable<FieldInfo> DeclaredFields
public virtual IEnumerable<MemberInfo> DeclaredMembers
public virtual IEnumerable<MethodInfo> DeclaredMethods
public virtual IEnumerable<System.Reflection.TypeInfo> DeclaredNestedTypes
public virtual IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> DeclaredProperties
public virtual IEnumerable<Type> ImplementedInterfaces

public virtual EventInfo GetDeclaredEvent(String name)
public virtual FieldInfo GetDeclaredField(String name)
public virtual MethodInfo GetDeclaredMethod(String name)
public virtual IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetDeclaredMethods(String name)
public virtual System.Reflection.TypeInfo GetDeclaredNestedType(String name)
public virtual PropertyInfo GetDeclaredProperty(String name)
```

Данные методы не содержат какой-либо специальной логики и являются обёртками над существующими в `Type`, поэтому архитектурно было бы неправильно тащить их в новый `DelayLoadType`. Отчасти поэтому иерархия типов была разделена. `DelayLoadType` стал наследником `Type`, а все остальные реализации наследуются от `TypeInfo`, а уж он в свою очередь - от `Type`. Всё, что вы можете сделать через `Type`, вы можете сделать через `TypeInfo` и наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

В .NET Core 1.0-1.1 часть функциональности из класса Type перенесли в TypeInfo. Соответственно, и .NET Standart как общее подмножество также не имеет этой функциональности в классе Type.

Для совместимости в .NET Framework TypeInfo тоже добавили - но если вы используете только .NET Framework и не собираетесь никуда переезжать - этот класс вам не нужен; можно и дальше везде использовать Type.

А вот если вы пишите для .NET Core 1.0-1.1 или переносимую библиотеку для .NET Standart ниже 2.0 - у вас просто не получится использовать Type так, как вы привыкли - там осталось совсем немного методов. Часть кода придется переписать на использование TypeInfo.

Comment: Ну т.е -это некий синтаксический сахар или взаимозаменяемы?

Comment: Они **не** взаимозаменяемы и **не** являются сахаром. Это два **разных** класса с разными возможностями.

Comment: А можете раскрыть в ответе то чего они может делать и чего другой не может делать и наоборот?

Comment: @iluxa1810 просто создайте приложение .NET Core или библиотеку под .NET Standart - и увидите сами.

Comment: "В чем разница между Type и TypeInfo?" в чем то есть, а в чем не понятно. "просто создайте приложение .NET Core или библиотеку под .NET Standart - и увидите сами"

Comment: @PavelMayorov а можно подробнее про `придётся переписать на использование TypeInfo`? Я не вижу принципиальных отличий между .NET Core и .NET Framework в части иерархии типов.

Comment: @LunarWhisper извиняюсь за неточность, не заметил что в свежей версии API вернули на место. Поглядите на более старые версии - там отличие прямо-таки в глаза бросается, большей части методов в Type нету.